# Margin not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have the following XML file to implement a fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="@dimen/two_third_width"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/extra_margin"
android:background="@drawable/found_item_bg"
tools:context=".FoundItemFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/found_item_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/extra_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/BlueText"
    android:textSize="@dimen/big_title_font" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/found_item_catnum_name"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_bg_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/found_item_description"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/big_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/item_name_bg"
    android:text="@string/catalog_number"
    android:textSize="@dimen/found_item_font" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/found_item_catnum_value"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/item_bg_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/found_item_catnum_name"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/found_item_catnum_name"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/small_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/item_value_bg"
    android:textSize="@dimen/found_item_font" />

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

No matter what value I give to the TextView elements' right margins, I get the following rendering:
[image: layout]

The first problem is that the found_item_description text has disappeared somewhere.  The main problem is that the three TextViews on the right are supposed to be inside the layout, not extended out the right side.  I have tried all sorts of values for layout_marginRight, but the various values seem to have no effect.  I assume something is overriding or neutralizing the margin value, but I don't understand what it might be.

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer, I'll check it.  This comes as an unhappy surprise, since I would have liked to have a default value for the other three sides, but I guess you can't have everything you want.

Comment: As you wish I moved answer to post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `layout_margin` and `layout_marginRight` in the same element. In that case only layout_marign will be applied. If you want different margin for only one side you have to add all `marginLeft`, `marginRight`, `marginTop` and `marginBottom`

Answer (score 0):

Side note: I'd suggest using `android:layout_marginStart` for right-to-left languages.